# How many concurrent TCP connections are supported in Windows Server OSs?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2012, tcp

I am distributing software in the form of a Windows service that can be installed, and am currently trying to ascertain the specifications for supported operating systems.

The service communicates with a number of clients (using our client software) on a TCP connection. Each client also has an open remote SQL connection to an SQL server running on the same PC as the service.

Currently I am aware of the current limitations:

- Windows Vista Starter and Home basic  - 5 simultaneous connections
- Windows Vista Home Premium and above - 10 simultaneous connections
- Windows 7 - 20 simultaneous connections
- Windows 8 - 20 simultaneous connections

My first question is: Do connections to the SQL server count towards these limits, and if they do, does that mean Windows 7, for example, can only support 10 clients (20/2)?

Secondly, on Windows Server operating systems (particularly Server 2008 R2 and Server 2012) are these limitations still governed by the number of CAL licenses, or is there a strict limit? For example, I read that Server 2008 Foundation only supports 30 (the MS documentation helpfully says that Standard and above support more, but does not specify how many).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where are you getting the limitations list from?

Comment: Various sources, Microsoft Documentation. Some testing we did

Comment: Unless I am confusing SMB connections?

Comment: I think you're getting mixed up... See this article - http://www.serverframework.com/asynchronousevents/2010/12/one-million-tcp-connections.html

Comment: These limitations are incorrect.

Comment: @surfasb Those are the limitations given on the Microsoft website. If they're incorrect could you do something helpful, like, I don't know, give the correct ones?